# Kubernetes cluster on Raspberry Pi stops working 5 minutes after init

Tags: kubernetes, containerd, raspberry-pi-os, etcd

I had set up a Kubernetes cluster on four Raspberry Pis for toy projects awhile back, and I originally set things up using Docker. But ever since Kubernetes decided to drop support for Docker I decided to re-do the cluster using ContainerD instead. On top of that, I wiped the SD cards and installed the x64 version of Raspberry Pi OS (instead of the 32-bit version which I was using previously). I've slowly been piecing together a runbook of how to install things but have encountered a snag: five minutes after calling `kubeadm init` on the master node, the cluster stops working. For reference, the internal IP of my master node is 192.168.1.194. Here's the full command I use to initialize things:

```
sudo kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 \
    --token-ttl=0 --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.1.194
```

After running that command, and subsequently copying the /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf file to ~/.kube/config, I can run the following command:

```
$ kubectl get nodes

NAME           STATUS     ROLES                  AGE     VERSION
k8s-master-1   NotReady   control-plane,master   3m36s   v1.23.4
```

And it will continue to show a `NotReady` status for about 5 minutes, after which point the same command yields a very different result:

```
$ kubectl get nodes

The connection to the server 192.168.1.194:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

I'm not sure why this is happening, but it is very consistent. I have tried a few times now to `kubeadm reset` and then `kubeadm init` again, and the connection timeout always happens at the 5-minute mark. So the last time I tried to do this, I decided to tail all the log files under /var/log/containers/. After the 5-minute mark, it is repeatedly logging some variation of a connection error to 127.0.0.1:2379. For example:

> 2022-03-09T19:30:29.307156643-06:00 stderr F W0310 01:30:29.306871       1 clientconn.go:1331] [core] grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {127.0.0.1:2379 127.0.0.1  0 }. Err: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused". Reconnecting...

But prior to the 5-minute mark, it looks like a bunch of services start shutting down right at the end, followed by what looks like maybe etcd shuts down as well. I've uploaded the full logs from the time `kubeadm init` runs, up until the dreaded 5-minute mark, [as a Gist](https://gist.github.com/soapergem/fd71b313473aa366e5bb44acdaccaab4).

Why won't Kubernetes start on my Pi? What am I missing?

Comment: does all the ports are open? could you do test all ports like  `telnet localhost 2379`.
Ref docs for all the ports: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/ports-and-protocols/

Comment: Yes, all ports are open. The telnet command succeeds during that first 5 minute window of initialization, while etcd is active.

Comment: if all steps are correct and it is failing then what i can think of is `kubeadm join` is not able to bring this node in cluster. there could be multiple reason for that. may be you could try to specify the `--control-plane-endpoint` while configuring the cluster which is basically your cluster endpoint. 
Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#:~:text=While%20%2D%2Dapiserver%2Dadvertise,supported%20by%20kubeadm

Comment: Again, this is not one of the nodes but the master, so `kubeadm join` is not used.